# Any way to bypass the need to map new variables to tuple values returned from a python function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, return, tuples

Here is my working code example:

```
def load_databases():
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file_directory+'data1.csv', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file_directory+'data2.csv', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
    df3 = pd.read_csv(file_directory+'data3.csv', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
    return df1, df2, df3
df1_new, df2_new, df3_new = load_ref_databases()
```

To use this function, I need to remember the order and nature of the returned output values (`df1`, `df2`, `df3`). And I need to make sure the order of the new variables (`df1_new`, `df2_new`, `df3_new`) needs to map with the function's tuple output. Is there a better way to map the tuple values? Or better yet, bypassing the need of this line:

```
df1, df2, df3 = load_ref_databases()
```

So that when I run `load_databases()`, `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` will be created and accessible as global variables?

Comment: If remembering is the issue, there's always docstrings: `"""Returns in order (data1.csv, data2.csv, data3.csv)"""` which can then be easily accessed with `help(load_databases)`

Comment: Thanks, I just want to make sure this is the good/best practice of handling function that returns multiple values.